# Border effect to LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I would like to get linearlayout border effect like the image below:

[image]

Is this possible? I don't wanna use one layout inside another layout. If so how do I do it?

I tried the following:

```
<corners android:radius="4dp" />

<stroke
    android:width="4dp"
    android:color="@color/layoutcolor_net" />

<gradient
    android:endColor="#BDBDBD"
    android:gradientRadius="250"
    android:startColor="#E0E0E0"
    android:type="radial" />

<padding
    android:bottom="30dp"
    android:left="30dp"
    android:right="30dp"
    android:top="30dp" />
```

I apply the gradient properly but my text is not shown.

I am applying this to relativeLayout:

```
                <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/receivedLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".33"
                android:background="@drawable/gradientShow"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/receivedImage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/recieved"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/receivedText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/receivedImage"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/transaction_received"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should checkout the 'shape drawables' section of the reference guide.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

There are lots of things you can do with shapes. For example:

```
<shape 
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#FFFF0000"
    android:endColor="#80FF00FF"
    android:angle="45"/>
<padding android:left="7dp"
    android:top="7dp"
    android:right="7dp"
    android:bottom="7dp" />
<corners android:radius="8dp" />
```

save that file as res/drawables/gradient.xml folder and refer to it like this in a textview or some other view:

```
<TextView
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: I am already trying it but I don't get the textView. Can you please let me know what could be wrong? Please check my updated question.

Comment: @ Martin:  Hey! Can you please help with the above issue. Thanks!

Comment: Change TextView to LinearLayout

Comment: @ Martin: I didn't use yours, tried a different style. Applied it on Relative Layout. The ImageView is coming up which is inside relative layout but the textView is not showing it is blank? any idea why this is happening?

Comment: relativelayout means you have to specify where views are located, relative to X.  X can be another view, a side, etc. You didn't specify, so the textview buried under the imageView.  Try adding layout_Below